# Legend tag child button click not working in the chrome

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

My code as follow. it is working in IE properly.
only legend border is clickable in chrome. if i remove legend tag, i can click to button.
Any solution to this problem?

```html
<fieldset class="border p-2">
    <legend style="width:auto">
        <button class="repeatButton" onclick="add_to_group2('id1')">+</button>
    </legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: legend tag ahs follow css values; legend {
        padding: 0px;
    }

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```js
function onBtn(cosr) {
  alert(cosr);
}
```

```css
legend {
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    <button onclick="onBtn('legend')">Click Here</button>
  </legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: my legend tag has padding: 0px; value. if i remove this, It works like your code. But i dont understand why padding attribute cause this problem. Thanks

Comment: Please share a snippet to reproduce the issue.